# How to show a dialog when notification is clicked, while the app being closed

Tags: android

I want to implement the feature as in some To-do apps, so that when I click on a notification, it shows a dialog to quickly create a to-do instantly, by **not** opening the app.

Comment: would you like to share what you have tried so far?

Comment: you could make your pendingIntent open an activity with theme Dialog

Comment: What you have tried to implement this feature ?

Comment: that's not possible. A dialog requires a context

Comment: You can look at [https://github.com/slimhippo/androidcode](https://github.com/slimhippo/androidcode)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly from your question, you need to show a dialog only and not to launch application. If yes, then you can open/launch an activity as a dialog by using:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

you can have a pending intent for it and set it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DialogActivity.class);
PendingIntent dialogPendingIntent = 
PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),REQUEST_ID, intent,
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);  
notfication.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Please make sure DialogAcitivity does not extends AppcompatAcivity, if you do need to provide backward support, then use "Theme.AppCompat.Dialog" as style.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

- Show your dialog in a transparent activity.

OR

- You can create floating views in android.